# How to use two pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have 3 Tables:

***1) user***

```
 id    name
 1     abc
 1     abc
 2      tyu
 2      tyu
```

***2) phone***

```
    id     number
     1     0987654
     1     0890764
     2     3445667
     2     5643456
```

***3) address***

```
id     addr  type
 1    usa    1
 1    uae    1 
 2    Uk     2
```

***So now I have written below query:***

```
select * from (
              select u.id, u.name , p.number, cs.COL + CAST(row_number()over(PARTITION BY u.ID ORDER BY cs.COL) AS VARCHAR) RN ,
              cs1.COL + CAST(row_number()over(PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY cs1.COL) AS VARCHAR) RN1
               ,a.addr
              from user u left join phone p on p.id = u.id
              left join address as a on a.id = p.id CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('phone',number)) CS(Col,val)
                                                          CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('add',a.addr)) CS1(Col,val)
              where u.id=1 and a.type = '1'
              )P
    PIVOT (MAX(number) FOR RN IN ([phone1],[phone2])) as pivot1
    PIVOT (MAX(addr1)  FOR RN1 IN ([add1],[add2])) as pivot2
```

***so the above query give me output like:***

```
id  name    phone1      phone2      add1        add2
1   abc     NULL        0987654     NULL       usa
1   abc     0890764      NULL       uae         NULL
```

***but I want the ouput like below:***

```
  id    name    phone1      phone2      add1        add2
    1   abc     0890764     0987654     uae         usa
```

***So how can I achieve this with the pivot?***

Comment: I threw together some test data to have a go, but when I ran your query I got invalid column name 'IDnum' and invalid column name 'addr1'. Can you correct your post so that your sample query is in line with your sample data please.

Comment: @BeanFrog have updated. Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @user TABLE 
    (id int, name varchar(3))
;    
INSERT INTO @user
    (id, name)
VALUES
    (1, 'abc'),
    (1, 'abc'),
    (2, 'tyu'),
    (2, 'tyu')
    ;
declare @phone  TABLE 
    (id int, number int)
;   
INSERT INTO @phone
    (id, number)
VALUES
    (1, 0987654),
    (1, 0890764),
    (2, 3445667),
    (2, 5643456)
;
declare @address TABLE 
    (id int, addr varchar(3), type int)
;  
INSERT INTO @address
    (id, addr, type)
VALUES
    (1, 'usa', 1),
    (1, 'uae', 1),
    (2, 'Uk', 2)
;

select id,name,MAX(phone1)phone1,max(phone2)phone2,max(add1)add1,max(add2)add2 from (
              select u.id, u.name , p.number, cs.COL + CAST(row_number()over(PARTITION BY u.ID ORDER BY cs.COL) AS VARCHAR) RN ,
              cs1.COL + CAST(row_number()over(PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY cs1.COL) AS VARCHAR) RN1
               ,a.addr
              from @user u left join @phone p on p.id = u.id
              left join @address as a on a.id = p.id CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('phone',number)) CS(Col,val)
                                                          CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('add',a.addr)) CS1(Col,val)
              where u.id=1 and a.type = '1'
              )P
    PIVOT (MAX(number) FOR RN IN ([phone1],[phone2])) as pivot1
    PIVOT (MAX(addr)  FOR RN1 IN ([add1],[add2])) as pivot2
    group by id,name
```

Comment: @siddharth already you have done all the work..just max of the values I have taken

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the data into a slightly different format before you pivot. 
You were along the right lines, but combine the columns RN and RN1 into one, and then pvioting works on them both at the same time - as follows.

```
select id, name, [phone1], [phone2], [add1], [add2]
from (
    select u.id, u.name, pa.columnname, pa.value from 
    user u inner join
    (
        select id, number as value, 'phone' + cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by number) as char(1)) as columnname
        from phone
        union all  
        select id, addr, 'add' + cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by addr) as char(1)) as columnname
        from address where type = 1
    ) as pa
        on pa.id = u.id
    ) as base
pivot (max(value) for columnname in ([phone1], [phone2], [add1], [add2])) p
where id = 1;
```